# filter array of objects and add object if condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

This is my array

```
{"idSect":55, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":55, "denumireSpece":"Hematologie"},
{"idSect":32, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":27, "denumireSpece":"Dermatovenerologie"},
{"idSect":21, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":57, "denumireSpece":"Medicina nucleara"},
{"idSect":53, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":32, "denumireSpece":"Medicina naturista"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":1,  "denumireSpec":"Cardiologie"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":59, "denumireSpec":"Psihiatrie pediatrica"},
```

From it, I want to get a computed array which looks like this:

```
{"idSpec":55, "nameSpec":"Hematologie",    "leg": true},
{"idSpec":27, "nameSpec":"Dermatovenerologie",    "leg": true},
{"idSpec":57, "nameSpec":"Medicina nucleara",     "leg": true},
{"idSpec":32, "nameSpec":"Medicina naturista",    "leg": true},
{"idSpec":1,  "nameSpec":"Cardiologie",           "leg": false},
{"idSpec":59, "nameSpec":"Psihiatrie pediatrica", "leg": false},
```

I want the 'leg' attribute to only be true if that object's 'idSect' isn't null.

How may I do this in a computed property?

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you would really need to do is remap your array with the values you would like, and call that in your computed property. You can use [array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in JAvascript, the map function creates a new array by calling a function for every array element, in this case remapping our values.

Given the above array that would translate to:

```
var exampleArr = [{"idSect":55, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":55, "denumireSpece":"Hematologie"},
{"idSect":32, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":27, "denumireSpece":"Dermatovenerologie"},
{"idSect":21, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":57, "denumireSpece":"Medicina nucleara"},
{"idSect":53, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":32, "denumireSpece":"Medicina naturista"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":1,  "denumireSpec":"Cardiologie"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":59, "denumireSpec":"Psihiatrie pediatrica"}]

var remappedArr = exampleArr.map(x =>  ({idSpec: x.idSpec, nameSpec: x.denumireSpece , leg: Boolean(x.idSect)}) );
```

Which in turn will result in the following structure (not sure if by design but 'denumireSpece' misses an 'e' on some objects).

```
[
    { idSpec: 55, nameSpec: 'Hematologie', leg: true },
    { idSpec: 27, nameSpec: 'Dermatovenerologie', leg: true },
    { idSpec: 57, nameSpec: 'Medicina nucleara', leg: true },
    { idSpec: 32, nameSpec: 'Medicina naturista', leg: true },
    { idSpec: 1, nameSpec: undefined, leg: false },
    { idSpec: 59, nameSpec: undefined, leg: false }
  ]
```

The only thing left would be to create a computed property in vuejs.

```
computed: {
    myArray: {
      get() {
        return this.myArray.map(x => ({idSpec: x.idSpec, nameSpec: x.denumireSpece , leg: Boolean(x.idSect)}) );
      },
   }
}
```

Comment: Can it be that the 'idSect' for those objects are all null? Given that we don't have the code it might be a good idea to add a breakpoint on the .map statement to see how the values are being mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [
    { idSect: 55, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 55, denumireSpece: 'Hematologie' },
    { idSect: 32, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 27, denumireSpece: 'Dermatovenerologie'},
    { idSect: 21, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 57, denumireSpece: 'Medicina nucleara' },
    { idSect: 53, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 32, denumireSpece: 'Medicina naturista'},
    { idSect: null, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 1, denumireSpece: 'Cardiologie' },
    { idSect: null, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 59, denumireSpece: 'Psihiatrie pediatrica' },
]

const newArray = arr.map(({ idSect, idSpec, denumireSpece }) => ({
    idSpec,
    nameSpec: denumireSpece,
    leg: Boolean(idSect),
}))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [
{ idSect: 55, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 55, denumireSpece: "Hematologie" 
},
{
idSect: 32,
DenumireSect: null,
idSpec: 27,
denumireSpece: "Dermatovenerologie",
},
{
idSect: 21,
DenumireSect: null,
idSpec: 57,
denumireSpece: "Medicina nucleara",
},
{
idSect: 53,
DenumireSect: null,
idSpec: 32,
denumireSpece: "Medicina naturista",
},
{ idSect: null, DenumireSect: null, idSpec: 1, denumireSpec: "Cardiologie" 
},
{
idSect: null,
DenumireSect: null,
idSpec: 59,
denumireSpec: "Psihiatrie pediatrica",
},
];

let newArr = [];

arr.map((item) => {
 if (item.idSect !== null) {
   newArr.push({ ...item, leg: true });
 }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/kathirvel08/y75ra3o9/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<script setup>
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue'

const array1 = reactive([{"idSect":55, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":55, "denumireSpece":"Hematologie"},
{"idSect":32, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":27, "denumireSpece":"Dermatovenerologie"},
{"idSect":21, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":57, "denumireSpece":"Medicina nucleara"},
{"idSect":53, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":32, "denumireSpece":"Medicina naturista"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":1,  "denumireSpece":"Cardiologie"},
{"idSect":null, "DenumireSect":null, "idSpec":59, "denumireSpece":"Psihiatrie pediatrica"}])

const filtered = computed(() => array1.map(item => 
 item={idSpec: item.idSpec, nameSpec:item.denumireSpece, leg: item.idSect!==null}
 )
);
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(value, key, index) in array1">
          {{ value.idSect !== null }}
        </li>
  </ul>
  <pre>{{filtered}}</pre>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).